# bash script that computes used diskspace percentage for given partition

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that computes used diskspace percentage for given partition:

```
    df -k $devname | grep -v ^File | awk '{printf ("%i",$3*100 / $2); }
```

it doesn't work on a partition with long name because the name pushes the other columns to the next line, how do I fix this?

```
df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup60-ROOT
                     2865493440 2222006740 497927968  82% /
tmpfs                 30913808         0  30913808   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1               495844    103347    366897  22% /boot
```

Comment: check out other options to `df`, there is one that keeps everything on the same line (maybe as a side effect of some other property). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-P` (portability) option for `df` use a output format compliant with posix and keeps everything in one line. You can also simplify the `awk` part using [`sel`](https://github.com/slezica/sel).

Answer (score 6):

Instead of parsing the entire "table" you could output the usage in percentage directly by using the `--output` parameter (see [`man 1 df`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/df.1.html) for details):

```
$ df -k --output=pcent /dev/sda1
Use%
 13%
```

That should be a lot easier to filter.

E.g. by creating an array with `readarray` in Bash 4:

```
$ readarray -t -s 1 percentage < <(df -k --output=pcent /dev/sda1)
$ echo "${percentage[0]// /}"
13%
```

Assigning the output of `df` to an array line by line:

```
$ percentage=($(df -k --output=pcent /dev/sda1))
$ echo "${percentage[1]}"
13%
```

Comment: +1 Your solution made me re-read the man-page for different `FIELD_LIST` for `--output` parameter. Good stuff.

Comment: Heh thanks - from my experience many tools which offer data in some kind of a table also offer a parameter to gather specific parts of that data. Applies to e.g. `smartctl` or `nvidia-smi`, too. :)